# Dead Link: Link opens in new window, but not on the page

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

**The problem:**
I have a link on a page that when I click it, nothing happens, but when I right click and open in a new window, I get the image that is on the link.  I've used Firefox and Chrome.  I'm doing web development on my localhost before deploying to our dev environment.  It works in DEV, but not on local; it had worked previously on local.  This doesn't make sense to me.

**The solution:**
I did a checkout of the pages I had been working on from our svn repository.  And that didn't work.

Would I be right in thinking if the link opened in a new window then the problem is something else?

**This Link:**

```
<a type="hidden" class="highlight" id="hidden_link" href="../images/developer_notice.png"></a>
```

**Is clicked by this form:**

```
<form action="" id="search-form" name="search-form" method="get" onsubmit="return validateSearchForm();">
```

**Via these javascripts:**

```
function validateSearchForm(){
 if(!validateAccountStanding()){
    return false;
 }

 return true;
}

function validateAccountStanding(){
var accountStanding = $("#account_standing").val();

//check account standing, if it's "Not Good," alert user
//otherwise, keep going, business as usual.
if(accountStanding == "Not Good"){
    document.getElementById('hidden_link').click();
alert("!");
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

I'm using fancybox to display the 'notice' to the user.

```
<!-- Enable fancy box -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //$.noConflict();
    $("a.highlight").fancybox(); 
});
</script>
<!-- Enable fancy box /end -->
```

I get to the alert when that form is submitted.
This worked on my local previously.

Error Message from Firefox:
u is undefined
/ccdev2/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js
Line 17

Comment: Did you look in the error console in Firefox or chrome to see if you are getting in errors?

Comment: I added it to the question.  It looks like I will have to find an upacked jquery.fancybox-1.3.1 from somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question after I Googled "U is undefined."

[Jquery error "u is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820090/jquery-error-u-is-undefined)

That fixed me up.  I had declared fancybox in another php file that is included on this page.  That was the one file I *forgot* to reset.